# ftp download completes, but unzip says otherwise

Tags: linux, perl, ftp, zip, unzip

I ran into a bizzarre error on linux:

I download a file using Net::FTP.  Once get() method returns, I call the system unzip function:

```
   system("unzip -j $file");
```

the majority of the time, it looks as though the downloaded file didn't quite finish:

```
   error [<filepath>]:  missing 1862 bytes in zipfile
```

Why would something like this happen? I suppose, I can write code to wait and handle the error, but why isn't the filesystem updated when Net:FTP::get() returns?

Comment: did you set up the binary transfer mode with Net::FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right.  Needed to set binary mode for ftp transfer.

Whatever made it decide to go ascii?  I thought binary was automatic nowadays.  It's not!